# Java stream sorting objects based on the double value

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have list of `X1` objects and trying to sort the list based on method `obj_function()` which returns `Double` value.

```
result = custom_obj_list.stream()
    .sorted((x1,x2) -> {
        return -x1.obj_function().compareTo(x2.obj_function());
    }).filter((x2) -> { 
        return x2.obj_function <= 1; 
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I'm struggling to solve the below error message

> stream().sorted() cannot resolve symbol or cannot resolve method

Comment: `.sorted(x1,x2) -> {` is not a valid syntax

Comment: `.sorted(x1,x2)` - You're missing a `(`

Comment: Also, if your lambda is just a single return you don't need a block scope. i.e `(x, y) -> { return x + y; }` can be simplified to `(x, y) -> x + y`

Comment: *`Cannot resolve method ...`* You left out the most important part.

Comment: `compareTO` – You're sure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [Comparator.comparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) instead of lambda expression, If you just want default sorting order

```
result = custom_obj_list.stream()
                        .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(X1::obj_function))  //X1 should be class name
                        .filter(x2 -> x2.obj_function() <= 1)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or reverse sorting order

```
result = custom_obj_list.stream()
                        .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(X1::obj_function).reverse()))   ////X1 should be class name
                        .filter(x2 -> x2.obj_function() <= 1)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Probably want to look a bit more into this one. You're using `obj_function` as both a method and a field.

Comment: thanks, i do see he mentioned it as method and updated the code according to that @flakes

Comment: Come to think of that, this is probably OP's issue. I bet their definition of `obj_function` is actually an `int`, causing the method resolution error lol

Comment: If can be `Integer` also, but if it is `int` he can use `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-` @flakes i will just wait for him to come back

Comment: sry, it is a `Double`, what `obj_function` returns

Comment: I tried your solution, it works half-way, i'm still getting `Cannot resolve method obj_function` on `x2.obj_function()`

Comment: you can use `comparingDouble`, can you show the `X1` class? does that have `obj_function()` method? @Mike

Comment: `public Double obj_function() {
        return this.atrb1;
    }`, this is how the obj_function is declared and in X1 class i have a `private Double atrb1;` declared